# Prevent service from starting

Tags: linux, systemd

The idea is to create a `keep-down.service` that never starts:

```
[Unit]
Description=Keeps daemon down

Before=mydaemon.service
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/var/lib/dummy-never-existing-path

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So it's needed by the `mydaemon.service`. While `keep-down.service` is installed, the `mydaemon.service` can't start (theoretically).

Motivation:

- no `systemctl` commands can start the `mydaemon.service`
- no modifications to the `mydaemon.service` unit file
- no messing with the config of the `mydaemon.service`
- it's atomic: installing/removing the `keep-down.service` custom package

The problem is that `mydaemon.service` starts anyways. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified that your `keep-down` service must start *before* `mydaemon.service`:

```
Before=mydaemon.service
```

But you haven't actually configured any dependency between the two, such as:

```
RequiredBy=mydaemon.service
```

Details are in the `systemd.unit` man page, which for example says this about `Before=` and `After=`:

> Note that this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the 
>   requirement dependencies as configured by Requires=. It is a common 
>   pattern to include a unit name in both the After= and Requires= 
>   option, in which case the unit listed will be started before the
>   unit that is configured with these options.

However, all of this is really unnecessary.  You can accomplish with you want using the `systemctl mask` command:

```
   mask NAME...
       Mask one or more unit files, as specified on the command line. This
       will link these units to /dev/null, making it impossible to start
       them. This is a stronger version of disable, since it prohibits all
       kinds of activation of the unit, including enablement and manual
       activation. Use this option with care. This honors the --runtime
       option to only mask temporarily until the next reboot of the
       system. The --now option can be used to ensure that the units are
       also stopped.
```

So:

```
# systemctl mask mydaemon
```

Comment: `mask` is a bit too dynamic to place it in the package. `RequiredBy` doesn't help: `keep-down` reports `start condition failed`, but `mydaemon` still starts. Have to fail `keep-down.sevice` completely to disable `mydaemon.service`.